# I am using a git repo called LikeButton, but the state of my button keeps jumping around in my recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, button, android-recyclerview

I am using a git repo called LikeButton, but the state of my button keeps jumping around in my recyclerview? Here is the repo https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton. Basically when I click on a recyclerview item, it sets a textview to the word true or false based on if the user liked the post or not, and this works. However, the state of my button is doing some weird stuff, it jumps around...
Here is my Adapter, is their anything wrong with it?

```
public class ViewpagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewpagerAdapter.ViewDashboard>{
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private ArrayList<QuestionData> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewpagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setBloglist(ArrayList<QuestionData> listBlogs) {
        this.data = listBlogs;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0,listBlogs.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewDashboard onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customizejson, parent, false);
        ViewDashboard viewholder = new ViewDashboard(view);
        return viewholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewDashboard holder, int position) {
        QuestionData questionHolder = data.get(position);
        holder.questionText.setText(questionHolder.getMtext());
        //This sets the text, to a true or a false String
        holder.mStudentVoted.setText(questionHolder.getVoters());
        holder.mLikeButton.setTag(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class ViewDashboard extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView questionText;
        private LikeButton mLikeButton;
        private TextView mStudentVoted;
        public ViewDashboard(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            questionText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionText);
            mStudentVoted = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentVoted);

            mLikeButton = (LikeButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_viewpager);

            mLikeButton.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
                @Override
                public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                    Voting voting = new Voting(getAdapterPosition(),ViewpagerAdapter.this, questionId);
                    voting.onUpVote();
                }

                @Override
                public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                    Voting voting = new Voting(getAdapterPosition(),ViewpagerAdapter.this, questionId);
                    voting.onDownVote();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Voting Class

```
public class Voting {

private int adapterPosition;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private String stringId;
private TextView studentVoted;
//TODO Trim Constructor
public Voting(int adapterPosition,final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, TextView questionId, TextView studentVoted) {
    stringId = questionId.getText().toString();
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.studentVoted=studentVoted;
}

public void onUpVote() {

    final RequestQueue mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();

    StringRequest postVoteUp = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_VOTE_UP, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println("Succesful Upvote The Students Value is " + studentVoted);

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("failed Upvote");


        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(postVoteUp);
}
public void onDownVote() {
    final RequestQueue mrequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    //TODO Delete Token(inserted for student 3 for testing purposes)
    StringRequest postVoteDown = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_VOTE_DOWN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //TODO OnResponse, must setLiked(False)
            //Succesful downVote The Students Value is true
            //studentVoted.setText("false");

            System.out.println("Succesful downVote The Students Value is "+studentVoted);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            System.out.println("failed downVote");
        }
    });
    mrequestQueue.add(postVoteDown);
}
public void realTimeUpVoting(TextView textView){
    String voteString= textView.getText().toString();
    int voteNumber=Integer.parseInt(voteString)+1;
    textView.setText("" + voteNumber);
}
public void realTimeDownVoting(TextView textView){
    String voteString= textView.getText().toString();
    int voteNumber=Integer.parseInt(voteString)-1;
    textView.setText("" + voteNumber);
}
}
```

Json Request and Parsing Methods

```
public void JsonRequestMethod() {
    mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_HOME, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                mListblogs.clear();
                mListblogs = new YourTask().execute(response).get();

            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}

private ArrayList<QuestionData> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int x = 0; x < response.length(); x++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(x);
                JSONArray arrSubcategory = currentQuestions.optJSONArray("questions");
                for (int y = 0; y < arrSubcategory.length(); y++) {
                    JSONObject objectSubcategory = arrSubcategory.getJSONObject(y);
                    String text = objectSubcategory.optString("text");
                    String studentId = objectSubcategory.optString("studentId");
                    String votes=objectSubcategory.optString("votes");
                    /*JSONArray cycles through the array of voters, when a user votes
                    their ID is added to the array.When they downvote, it is removed
                     */
                    JSONArray voters= objectSubcategory.optJSONArray("voters");

                    QuestionData questionData = new QuestionData();
                    questionData.setMstudentId(studentId);
                    questionData.setMtext(text);
                    questionData.setVotes(votes);
                    questionData.setVoters(checkIfVoted(voters));
                    mQuestionDataArrayList.add(questionData);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return mQuestionDataArrayList;
}
private static String checkIfVoted(JSONArray jsonArray ) {
    /*pass in a json Array, copy the array into ints, and if
      the students Id is contained in the array return the string true
     */
    int[] voteIds = new int[jsonArray.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<voteIds.length;i++){
        voteIds[i] = jsonArray.optInt(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<voteIds.length;i++){
        if(voteIds[i]== Integer.parseInt(Login.getUserId())){
            //TODO String was only used for Testing purposes, Convert to Boolean later
            return "true";
        }
    }
    return "false";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you are currently only updating the textview which is why your recycleview changes state when scrolling.

Should change your voting class and pass the question Data rather textview

```
    public Voting(int adapterPosition,final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, TextView questionId, TextView studentVoted) {
```

change to

```
    public Voting(int adapterPosition,final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, QuestionData questionData, TextView studentVoted) {
   // make other changes for the data
```

and then in

```
public void realTimeUpVoting(QuestionData questionData){
data.votes++ //something like that. idont know your model
// now call back using interface the recyleview data changed method so it updates the count in recycleview automatically.
```

**Edit**

passing the question Data in click button

```
 class ViewDashboard extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public int position


 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewDashboard holder, int position) {
     holder.position = position
 }

 public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
     QuestionData questionHolder = data.get(position);
```

Comment: how do I pass the questionData from the Recyclerview?

Comment: you seem to be passing the textview though, you can just instead get the question data for that position

Comment: Thank You so much!